# Identity server connect always returns forbidden

Tags: c#, .net-core, web-hosting, duende-identity-server

I deployed

- Skoruba.Duende.IdentityServer.STS.Identity host on https://sso.cungthugian.com
- Skoruba.Duende.IdentityServer.Admin host on https://iadmin.cungthugian.com

on the share host and control by plesk.

I connect from admin site, I always get a forbidden error and discovery document https://sso.cungthugian.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

When I map and edit host file in local machine, that works great.

I try to fix in one week, I don't know how to fix it.

On the SSO, I got this error:

```
An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {49a42129-c09b-412e-bee5-df02c7878e2e} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
```

Comment: Your Anti forgery token handling may be misconfigured. [This article](https://medium.com/drunkcoding/anti-forgery-token-and-machine-key-6cb4cc65fc73) may be helpful.

Comment: I deploy on the share hosting, and control via plesk